# Galaxy Star fails Custom recovery flashing

Tags: samsung, odin

I've tried to flash my Galaxy Star Advance (SM-G350E) with ClockWorkMod recovery 6.0.2.9 using Odin and it has said "Success". But the stock recovery still exists and nothing has been flashed! 
How to flash the recovery? *USB debbugging* is ON and *Samsung USB drivers* are installed

Comment: What exactly did you flash?

Comment: ClockWorkMod custom recovery 6.0.2.9 (recover.tar.md5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because when you flash custom recovery from Odin and allow it to reboot on its own, Samsung's *Recovery checking script* checks if a custom recovery is present and overrides it with *system recovery<3e>*.

To bypass that check you need to take your battery out as soon as the recovery is flashed by Odin (and before the phone reboots).

- As soon as the Odin says PASS(or SUCCESS) you should be ready to take out the battery which will stop it from rebooting,
- Put back the battery and enter recovery mode directly by pressing and holding Volume Up, Home and Power keys at the same time.
- Release all three buttons when Samsung boot screen flickers and the main screen of Recovery mode appears.
- This will avoid script checking and will let you to custom recovery directly